# Auto increment build number using PlatformIO

Tags: build, arduino, microcontroller, platformio

I have several micro controller projects for home automation. Each of my nodes have a version number which is manually set in the code. This version number is reported during the startup of the node to inform me which code is running.

Sometimes changing the version number is forgotten after making some changes in the code. So an automatic solution has to be found.

I have some idea about the solution:

1. create a file (version.h): #define BUILDNO xxx
2. include it in the relevant c codes
3. auto increment xxx before every build

Can it be implemented? Or are there any other solutions with similar result?

Comment: It seems like a good question, IMHO. At the very least it gives people an introduction to PlatformIO's custom scripts. (It did for me, at least!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have made some research based on answers to my question. PlatformIO can run custom scripts before compile. Here is the process to generate a build number and include it into your project code:

1. Create a Python script into the project folder: buildscript_versioning.py

```
FILENAME_BUILDNO = 'versioning'
FILENAME_VERSION_H = 'include/version.h'
version = 'v0.1.'

import datetime

build_no = 0
try:
    with open(FILENAME_BUILDNO) as f:
        build_no = int(f.readline()) + 1
except:
    print('Starting build number from 1..')
    build_no = 1
with open(FILENAME_BUILDNO, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(str(build_no))
    print('Build number: {}'.format(build_no))

hf = """
#ifndef BUILD_NUMBER
  #define BUILD_NUMBER "{}"
#endif
#ifndef VERSION
  #define VERSION "{} - {}"
#endif
#ifndef VERSION_SHORT
  #define VERSION_SHORT "{}"
#endif
""".format(build_no, version+str(build_no), datetime.datetime.now(), version+str(build_no))
with open(FILENAME_VERSION_H, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(hf)
```

2. Add a line to **platformio.ini**:

```
    extra_scripts = 
        pre:buildscript_versioning.py
```

Building your project will run the script. 2 files will be created:

- **versioning**: a simple text file to store the last build number
- **include/version.h**: header file to be included

Now you can add this line to your C code:

```
#include <version.h>
```

I started a gitlab repository with some documentation here: https://gitlab.com/pvojnisek/buildnumber-for-platformio/tree/master
Further ideas are welcome!

Comment: According to the [platformio docs](http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/advanced_scripting.html#launch-types), you need to prefix the script name with "pre:" if the script should execute before the build, other wise it will default to "post:" if there is no prefix.
Example:
`extra_scripts = \n
      pre:pre_extra_script.py \n
      post:post_extra_script1.py \n
`

Comment: Sorry for the bad code formatting, I can't see how to format multiline code in a comment. Have you also found a way to (re)name the file accordingly so it will be uploaded with the correct version number in the filename? i.e. firmware_0.1.2.bin

Comment: @EthanArnold Thank you for your comment! The pre and post prefixes are useful. I think pre: is the best solutution in this case. I will update the answer and the gitlab project also.

Comment: @EthanArnold have you managed to rename the bin file? It can be easily done in the python script. Simply use the following lines: 
`import os` and `os.rename(firmware.bin,f'firmware_{VERSION}.bin')`

Comment: While this would absolutely work, it may be nicer to use character arrays instead of preprocessor defines. If the preprocessor defines are changed, PIO has to recompile all the files in the compile unit (all libraries and such). Using character arrays allows PIO to only recompile the project source files that have the `version.h` file included. 

Comment: @Awbmilne Good point! Thank you for your comment! If you have some time please contribute to the repository!

Comment: I realize now that my earlier comment is not quite correct. In your solution, only the files referring to `version.h` are re-compiled. If you use the python script that I have outlined below, it _DOES_ cause a full recompile, since the #define effects every file in the compile unit. This is a great solution @pvoj! Might just have to incorporate it into my own!

Comment: Hello and thank you so much pvoj and @Awbmilne for providing those answers!
If you wish to easely rename the file with some timestamp, just add the following in the Python script : 
Import("env")
And at the end of the file : 
env.Replace(PROGNAME="firmware_%s" % version+str(build_no))

Comment: @pvoj Thanks a ton for this ready-to-use script. Works flawlessly and very useful for ArduinoOTA with web server ping.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with `git describe` and the PlatformIO's [advanced scripting](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/advanced_scripting.html).

First off, The project that I used this on relies heavily on git tags for version control. In my opinion, manually tracking version numbers in multiple places is a pain, it should all be based on the git tags. This makes CI and such really easy, Since I never forget to update the version in some file somewhere, It just need to refer to the git tags (regex protecting tags on github/gitlab helps too).

Using `git describe`, we can inject a commit description into the PIO build.

Here is an example:

`platformio.ini`

```
[env:my_env]
platform = teensy
board = teensy40
framework = arduino
extra_scripts = 
    pre:auto_firmware_version.py
```

`auto_firmware_version.py`

```py
import subprocess

Import("env")

def get_firmware_specifier_build_flag():    
    ret = subprocess.run(["git", "describe"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True) #Uses only annotated tags
    #ret = subprocess.run(["git", "describe", "--tags"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True) #Uses any tags
    build_version = ret.stdout.strip()
    build_flag = "-D AUTO_VERSION=\\\"" + build_version + "\\\""
    print ("Firmware Revision: " + build_version)
    return (build_flag)

env.Append(
    BUILD_FLAGS=[get_firmware_specifier_build_flag()]
)
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup(){
    serial.begin(115200);
    serial.print("Firmware Version: ");
    serial.println(AUTO_VERSION);   // Use the preprocessor directive

   // OR //

   char firmware_char_array[] = AUTO_VERSION;
   serial.println(firmware_char_array, sizeof(firmware_char_array));
}

void loop(){
    // Loop
}
```

With this configuration, you get the firmware version as a string literal. You can use it however you want since it is dealt with in the preprocessor and not compiler.

---

This, for example, will print the tag that the commit is aligned with:

```
v1.2.3
```

or, if there isnt a tag at the commit, the relation to the latest tag:

```
v1.2.3-13-gabc1234
└────┤ └┤  └─────┴─ Short commit Hash (not the g)
     │  └─ Distance from tag
     └─ Latest Tag in Git
```

---

You can customize this string however you like in the python script, For example:

```py
build_version = "My_Project_Firmware-" + ret.stdout.strip() + "-" + env['PIOENV'].upper()
```

would produce:

```
My_Project_Firmware-v1.2.3-13-gabc1234-MY_ENV
```

I use the `env['PIOENV']` to distinguish between different build environments, Useful if you have regular builds and debug builds.

---

Mostly a copy of a platformIO forum post:

> https://community.platformio.org/t/how-to-build-got-revision-into-binary-for-version-output/15380/5?u=awbmilne

Comment: Thank you for your description. I think this solution can be used in most of cases.

Comment: That was the hope 
The python script can be used to create just about any string desired. You can even just use a timestamp as an incrementing value.
So many options!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to depend on pre-build programs when using C or C++ (Arduino). You have to add a pre-build program which updates a file with a simple:

```
#define VERSION "1.0.0"
```

Your automatic increment program needs to store the current version somewhere (preferably inside the `version.h` so it won't get out of sync) and read, increment and store it upon compilation.

You can use a solution like this one from [vurdalakov](https://gist.github.com/vurdalakov/cc120a5ab0579e92f42c7711d982dbbe) or this one on [cplusadd.blogspot.com](http://cplusadd.blogspot.com/2008/12/automatic-build-number-generation.html) which uses Makefiles.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the question. It was very useful. It gave me some ideas where to start.
Since PlatformIO is multiplatform I migrated the linked code to Python which can be flawlessly run from the platform. I posted the final solution below.

Answer (score 1):

For my use-case I did **NOT** necessarily need an incremental number that is **always increased by one**, but any kind of ascending numbers is fine, therefore using timeticks was for me just fine.

In your platformio.ini:

```
[common]
firmware_version = '"0.1.0+${UNIX_TIME}"'

[env:release]
build_flags =
    -D FIRMWARE_VERSION=${common.firmware_version}
```

This shall give you a macro definition in the following format:

```
#define FIRMWARE_VERSION "0.1.0+1615469592"
```

Answer (score 1):

[autoinc-semver](https://github.com/rvdbreemen/autoinc-semver) is also a good solution for it.

You just have to include the `version.h` file in your code which looks as followed.

```
#define _VERSION_MAJOR 0 
#define _VERSION_MINOR 0
#define _VERSION_PATCH 1 
#define _VERSION_BUILD 41 
#define _VERSION_DATE 04-07-2020 
#define _VERSION_TIME 14:40:18 
#define _VERSION_ONLY 0.0.1 
#define _VERSION_NOBUILD 0.0.1 (04-07-2020) 
#define _VERSION 2.0.3+41 (04-07-2020)
```

And then you just have to add the `semver-build.bat ./version.h` or `semver-build.sh ./version.h` command as pre-built option to your compiler environment.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! It is something similar solution to the one mentioned before: https://gitlab.com/pvojnisek/buildnumber-for-platformio/tree/master but for Arduino IDE. As you mention it can be easily migrated to PlatfromIO.

Comment: autoinc-semver should run on almost all platforms which support C/C++ and it does not require the installation of Python. You just have to run the batchfile or shell script as pre-built command in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I like your solution for the problem. But wouldn't a version number based on the source code be more useful ?  PlatformIO has a section on dynamic build variables with an example that pulls a hash from the git source version
https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/section_env_build.html#id4 (scroll down to the Dynamic Build Variables section)

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I like it a lot.
Here the goal was to generate an incremental id. It is unique together with the date.
The id of the HEAD is a different story. It is depending on the current branch. You have to set it manually if you change branch during development (I personally open separate branches for each bugs and features).
Other solution could be using the `$UNIX_TIME` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't happy with any of the non-git answers, so here's a solution which is easier to customise. This will increment the #build by default.

**Make the file src/version.h**

```
#define VERSION "0.0.0+0
```

**Put this in a source file**

```
#include "version.h"
```

**Make a script autoincrement.py in the project root**

```
import sys, re, datetime

PATH_VERSION = './src/version.h'
MAJOR, MINOR, PATCH, BUILD = 0, 1, 2, 3

# Read
with open(PATH_VERSION, 'r') as reader:
  # Find "MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH+BUILD" from the first line
  line = re.search(r'"([^"]*)"', reader.readline()).group()[1:-1]
  # Extract old values for MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH+BUILD
  versions = re.split('\.|\+', line)
  # Increment value
  versions[BUILD] = int(versions[BUILD]) + 1

  # Write
  with open(PATH_VERSION, 'w') as writer:
    time = datetime.datetime.now()

    datestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    timestamp = time.strftime('%H:%M')
    version = '%s.%s.%s+%d' % (versions[MAJOR], versions[MINOR], versions[PATCH], versions[BUILD])
    versionFull = version + ' %s %s' % (datestamp, timestamp)

    writer.writelines([
      '#define VERSION "%s"' % version,
      '\n#define VERSION_MAJOR %s' % versions[MAJOR],
      '\n#define VERSION_MINOR %s' % versions[MINOR],
      '\n#define VERSION_PATCH %s' % versions[PATCH],
      '\n#define VERSION_BUILD %s' % versions[BUILD],
      '\n#define VERSION_DATE "%s"' % datestamp,
      '\n#define VERSION_TIME "%s"' % timestamp,
      '\n#define VERSION_FULL "%s"' % versionFull
    ])

    print('Release: ' + version)
```

**In platformio.ini, add this to your device**

```
extra_scripts = post:autoincrement.py
```

It'll then generate something the below in version.h

```
#define VERSION "0.0.1+68"
#define VERSION_MAJOR 0
#define VERSION_MINOR 0
#define VERSION_PATCH 1
#define VERSION_BUILD 68
#define VERSION_DATE "2022-11-27"
#define VERSION_TIME "23:35"
#define VERSION_FULL "0.0.1+68 2022-11-27 23:35"
```